# Anycubic Kobra Go bed leveling

Tags: bed-leveling, anycubic-kobra

I can’t figure out what the issue is. The far side of the bed (Y-axis) print won’t adhere because the extruder is too far off while on the near side is too thin. I have tried all the troubleshooting tips I can find online and nothing worked. Even as a last resort, I tried shimming the far-side bed screws and still have the same results after auto bed leveling.

[image: Photo of the first few layers of a printed model but front edge is very thin on the build plate]

[image: Another photo of a printed model again with a thin front edge]

Answer (score 0):

If you did not resolve this, you can try a couple of things:
You'd need OctoPrint and the "bedvisualizer" plugin installed.
I've had a similar problem with my Kobra standard and found out that it was totally off-level.
If the issues persist, please download/install both and send a screen capture of the bed level so we can go from there!

- [Setting up OctoPrint on Windows](https://community.octoprint.org/t/setting-up-octoprint-on-windows/383)
- [Bed Level Visualizer plugin](https://plugins.octoprint.org/plugins/bedlevelvisualizer/)